# Generate front-end based on database or java model

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I need to migrate the front-end of an application to angular. I want to use jhipster and reuse all existing java back-end and database. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to generate the front-end based on java model or i need to have the JDL files?
2. Is it possible to generate JDL files from the java model or from the database schema?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. No even though there has been some attempt like https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper but I don't think it will go far enough for you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.
I found another approach to generate the JDL files based on the database:
https://github.com/Blackdread/sql-to-jdl

I will try it.